# How to change a variable to something if it's undefined?

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I don't have my script completed yet or anything so I can't post the code. Basically I need a variable to change and keep going through a function increasing by one until it reaches its destination. Something like:

```
function one(a) {
    var x = a;
    var max = 3;
    if (a < 3) {
        // some code
        two(x);
    } else {
      // function will end here quitting the whole thing and possibly other code
    }
}
function two(x) {
    var change = x+1;
    one(change);

}
```

It all works how I need it but when I first enter function one how would I make it so when x = a doesn't have a value that it will by default be 0?

something like...

```
function one(a) {
    var x = a;
    var max = 3;
    if (x = undefined) {
      x = 0;
    } else {
        if (x < 3) {
            // some code
            two(x);
        } else {
          // function will end here quitting the whole thing and possibly other code
        }
    }
}
function two(x) {
    var change = x+1;
    one(change);

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does this do and what is the syntax? I've seen this while googling something similar and don't know what that is? Are the pipes the same syntax as in a command line interface like batch and bash for example?

Comment: I updated [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/pTVEb/1/) to explain it better.

Comment: @XRipperxMetalX - `a || 0` means if `a` is defined then assign `a` to `x`. If not, assign `0` to `x`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 It's not if a is defined, it has to be interpreted as `true`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
function one(a) {
    var x = a || 0;
    if (x < 3) {
        //debugger;
        two(x);
    } else {
        // function will end here quitting the whole thing and possibly other code
        alert('Done');
    }
}

function two(x) {
    x++;
    one(x);
}

one();
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/pTVEb/1/)**

`var x = a || 0` means `x` is `a` if `a` can be asserted as `true` or `0`.
`x++` means `x = x + 1`

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. Now I have a for loop in my script. Would the x++ confuse with anything by chance?

Comment: No, `x++` is just short for `x=x+1`. It's exactly the same.

Comment: The original code was not changing x in function two(), but since numbers are primitive types, they are passed by value, not reference, so it's fine.

EDIT: function two() could be shorter, but harder still to read:
 `function two(x) { one(++x); }`

Comment: @SamR I accidently wrote it as `one(x++)` but `one(++x)` works indeed. Explanation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26k41698(v=vs.94).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the variable is defined and send it in the functions argument by using the short hand conditional.

```
typeof(a)=="undefined" ? 0 : a;
```

You can change your code to:

```
function one(a) {
    var x = (typeof(a)=="undefined" ? 0 : a);
    var max = 3;
    if (x < 3) {
        // some code
        two(x);
    } else {
        // function will end here quitting the whole thing and possibly other code
        return;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gBBL2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = (typeof a === 'undefined') ? 0 : a;
```

If `a` is undefined, use `0`. Otherwise use `a` as the value of `x`.